# Can static_cast be used in C source code compiled by C compiler?

Tags: c++, c, static-cast

I saw C-library with code that compiled by GCC 11 that do `static_cast` from C code and it perfectly fine for GCC.

But **when I tried to compile this library in VisualStudio (MSVC) I got error**: (this library can be compiled by older VS2019(pre-2021 update))

```
fatal error C1189: #error: STL1003: Unexpected compiler, expected C++ compiler.
```

And only comment about it I saw there https://github.com/ofiwg/libfabric/issues/7041#issuecomment-914839351

> Hi! STL maintainer here. We made this change very recently in microsoft/STL#2148 which forbids including standard library headers from C programs.

Maybe im misunderstanding something, very confused.

Comment: `static_cast` is a c++ feature, only.

Comment: MSVC is right here. If your library uses C++ features in C then it's broken

Comment: The suggestion from the "STL maintainer" seems pretty clear. If the C code has an `#include <cstdxyz>`, change that to use the C header `#include "stdxyz.h"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_cast` is part of the C++ language, and more importantly it is **not** part of the C language, so attempts to use `static_cast<>` should cause a C compiler to emit compile-time errors.

If you've seen it successfully used in "C source code" anyway... one likely explanation is that the "C source" code was being compiled as C++ source code by a C++ compiler.  Since C++ is 99% backwards-compatible with C, most C source code can be compiled as C++ source code and will work, and in that scenario, `static_cast` could be part of the code and would compile.

Another possibility is that the compiler vendor got a bit sloppy and erroneously allowed a bit of their C++-specific functionality to execute even when compiling in the role of a C compiler, but hopefully that's not the case.

Comment: >  likely explanation is that the "C source" code was being compiled as C++ < (end quote)

(I do not want drop link to this project source code, it opensource, but it can be considered as witchhunt)
make file made by cmake, GCC compiles C source code that include .h file that has <static_cast>.... and GCC compile it, this .h file marked as ADD_LIBRARY with LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX ... but still that .h(with C++ code) file included by every C source code that compiled by GCC - for me this very confusing.

Comment: @DanilS What's confusing about that? It just means your code is compiled as C++ code. [gcc doesn't compile `static_cast` in C mode](https://godbolt.org/z/r8qj14Pan), so your project has wrong configuration (calling with wrong `-x` option) or wrong file extension (Files with extension `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `.C`... will be compiled in C++ mode)

Comment: I know that but whole "library source" in `.h` file that included by `.c` code that compiled by GCC, so how GCC can compile C code that include header file that has <static_cast> and how it can compile it. (it results in memory bugs, initially it was my bugreport to library that it has some corruption in memory... then I start testing/debugging... and found out that what I saying here - one of library that included by this C library made in C++... and somehow it works...)

Comment: @DanilS so you've called `g++` somewhere, or as I said, have the `-x c++` option somewhere in the project config so gcc ignores the `.c` extension. Are you sure that it's `.c` and not `.C`?

Comment: @phuclv I checked full make log on Linux - you correct about c++ compiler. Cmake compile using `/usr/bin/cc` every `*.c`(include that that includes header with C++ code) file into `-o *.c.o` but application built using all these `*.c.o` files by `/usr/bin/c++` in the end... this how gcc and g++ build it on linux, so `static_cast<>` literally compiled by gcc (C compiler) (there no extra flags for `cc` compiler)